# Should I use onclick for hiden/showing different sections on my website?

Tags: javascript

**Problem Statement:**

Imaging that each of the list items should show a new section, and hide the previous shown one. Eg. I click on `Home`" which will result in the currently shown one `Portfolio` now will be sat to `visibility:none;`, and the now requested section `Home` will be sat to `visibility:visible;`

**Why I am asking:**

I am a newbie to javascript and therefor have a very limited tool belt. For that reason I am asking you all-knowingly javascript gods for help.

- What would be the best way to achieve my problem statement?

**My (idea) approach:**      *(You don't have to read this)*
I was thinking about creating a `onclick` for each nav item that would trigger a javascript function. The javascript function would hide all sections, and depending on which onclick was clicked show that one section from the calling onclick. Is this a good approach? The draw back is that I am explicitly setting `visibility: none;` for all sections for each call. I assume that this could be a little cost expensive, or at least not the optimal solution.

[image]

*I do not assume that the html and css of the website on the picture is necessary to share here. But if it is, please write a comment saying that I should show it anyway.*

Comment: Yes you should use the click eventhandler

Comment: @Legends Is my approach (idea) a good solution?

Comment: AFAIK, this solution is fine.

Comment: Usually it is done like you mentioned. One could use also mouseenter, just by hovering over the menu entries you could show its content.
But I would say use onclick, because if the user wants to see a certain section he has to click explicitly on the menu entry, with mouseenter he could accidently show another section while moving his mouse pointer over the page

Comment: @Legends How do I parse an "event" argument into the onclick function, the event should be the tag that it is called from.

Comment: What do u mean with "parse"?

Comment: I am sorry that was badly worded. I want a onclick on each list item, they should each trigger the same function. But how do I keep track of which item called the function? - I was thinking that having an argument in the function that would point to the list item calling the function would help. But how do I implement this?